# Filter by area - how to include items with no physical location?

Tags: gui-design, filter, tags, location

I'm designing a filter component for a listings site. Within the filter component, users are able to filter by area by selecting/ unselecting checkboxes - pretty straightforward. The items to be filtered are businesses that offer services (i.e. mechanic, laundry, plumber, etc).

My issue is that there is a good portion of businesses that don't have a physical location. This means they don't have a shop or service centre you can physically visit, rather you get in touch with them by phone or by visiting their website and they'll come to you.

How can I factor in this case in the filters without confusing users?

I'm afraid users will overlook businesses without locations even though they might be of great service to them - probably because people are used to filtering physical locations this concept might be obscure to them.

Any suggestions, advice, comments? Thanks.

[image: Filter by Area example]

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Specify *On-line Service* as a location. It's more understandable, compared to *No Location*. Then Location header is more appropriate, compared to Area.
**Pro:** users can explicitly choose, if they want only services with physical locations

[image]

**Option 2**
Add on-line services to filtered by Area results if it's appropriate. Make smart guess, if the physical location is crucial for users. E.g. if they search for place to eat in Manhattan, on-line services are not appropriate. If they search for haircut in Manhattan, it's appropriate to add on-line services, which can came to your place to make haircut.
**Pro:** delivering good UX for users transparently, users make zero-efforts

[image]

In both case, think if your decision provides good UX for your users. And make it clear for users, if a service has no physical location, so user need to contact them.

Comment: in option 2, allow no Area checkbox to be selected (don't make the set of checkboxes behave like a radiobuttongroup where one must be selected)

Comment: also "online services" isn't really the best label; the distinction is between services with physical locations A, B, C,... and services that are DELIVERY ONLY.

Comment: Important:  many services only *deliver* to certain areas!  (so Area and "online"/"delivery only" are logical AND;  when choosing "delivery" are you now filtering on "delivery zones" instead of physical location???   or do you want (are you able) to allow searching for BOTH (OR logic) certain physical locations OR delivery to certain other delivery locations?